# Need suggestion on Push notifications

Tags: acumatica

We have a custom table without audit fields and we are using GI to expose data from a custom table. We have a stored procedure which fills the data into this custom table.

Is it possible to have push notifications for the table without audit fields?

We tried that originally, and it doesn't actually trigger any data push to the webhook. Not sure if this is relevant, but keep in mind that the changing of the data (insert, update or delete) is not done through Acumatica code but rather through stored procedures.

I'm not sure if that is the issue, or whether it's because it requires the standard Acumatica audit fields (or both). The underlying question is, what actually triggers the notification. Obviously, it's a change on the data set, but is when the underlying data changes, or is it triggered/monitored through the code layer as the data is being inserted/updated/deleted?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it quite easily.

For more information about push notification please take a look here : https://help-2019r1.acumatica.com/(W(3))/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=d8d2835f-5450-4b83-852e-dbadd76a5af8

for he Push Notification, you basically need 2 parts.

1. A data query
2. A destination

**The data query can be defined by either a generic inquiry or a built-in definition (which is a data query defined in code)**. And from what you are telling me you already have a generic inquiry.

So you would only need to create a proper destination for receiving the information.

Comment: Thanks for input Samol, i updated my question with some comments, please have a look.